# How to make drawableshape in Android using xml?

Tags: android

I need to make the below shape using xml.

[image]

I have created an oval shape using below xml code.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- This is the line -->

    <item android:height="400dp"><shape
        android:shape="oval">

        <solid android:color="#000000" />

    </shape></item>

</layer-list>
```

But I am not able to draw a line and circle together. Please help me to make the above shape using xml.

Comment: use nine patch drawable, not xml stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have come with a solution after little googling.

**Followed steps:-**

1.Created a xml file called dot.xml in drawable folder to draw a dot or filled circle.

```
//Dot.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval"  >
    <solid android:color="@color/colorTimeline" />
    </shape>
```

2.Inserted below code into layout file.

```
 <View
        android:id="@+id/v1"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorTimeline"
        android:contentDescription="ad"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v2"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dot"
        android:contentDescription="f"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/v1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"/>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/v3"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorTimeline"
        android:contentDescription="ad"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/v2"/>
```

**Final Output :-**

[Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0ytY.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:shape="oval">
           <solid android:color="@color/comment_background"/>
           <stroke android:color="@color/gray" android:width="0.5dp"/>
    </shape>
```

This is Code for Creating Circle shape in android

Answer (score 0):

My eyes bleeding, when i see your solution, sorry. I had to create and show you this one. Remember this example works only for known size of view. If you want to use dynamic values create my example drawable programatically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- VERTICAL LINE -->
    <item
        android:left="9dp"
        android:right="9dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid
                android:color="#FF0000" />
            <size
                android:width="2dp"
                android:height="200dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- OVAL -->
    <item
        android:top="90dp"
        android:bottom="90dp">

        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid
                android:color="#FF0000" />
            <size
                android:width="20dp"
                android:height="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

If you need any explanation just let me know.

Comment: @pskink Yes i know, but sometimes there are situations when u can't use best solution for any reason.